# How to insert a value to a variable while also trying to check if that value is zero

Tags: c

I'm having an assignment to complete where I need to find the zero body bias threshold voltage,based on the value of Vsb. Though this problem is based on the solution of another exercise, I give to you below some screenshots of what I need to calculate:
[image: Example 1.1: Threshold Voltage Calculation. It's the exercise on which the problem is based]

Where the Vthreshold formula is:

[image: Vthreshold voltage]

So I want to implement this:

[image: My problem]

My problem is that I don't know how to insert the Vsb value to the final formula in a way so that it can affect the final value of the zero body bias.The code that I've written returns only the value of the zero body bias based on the vthreshold only

Here's the code that I've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double vFB (double fgs, double B); 
double vT (double A, double C); 
double vA (double D); 
double vSP (double J); 
double gamwt (double A, double F); 
double roulis( double H, double L); 
double thres_volt(double vFB, double vSP, double vT, double vA); 
double zero_body_bias_threshold_voltage(double thresh_volt, double gamma, double roulis);

int main(){
    double eps0 = 8.854E-14; //Dielectric constant, void, [F/cm]
    double epsox = 3.9*eps0; //Oxide dielectric constant, [F/cm]
    double epsSi = 11.2*eps0; //Si dielectric constant, [F/cm]
    double q = 1.6E-19; // expressed in Coulomb
    double ni = 1.45E10; // intrincic carrier concentration expressed in cm^-3
    double Na = 1.0E15; // expressed in cm^-3
    double Ndpoly = 1.0E19; // expressed in cm^-3
    double xox = 100.0; //Oxide thickness,[A]
    double DI = 2.0E12; // number of implanted ions/cm^2 expressed in cm^-2
    double kTq = 0.026; // expressed in Volt
    double Qf = q*1.0E11;  //expressed in C/cm2
    double Vsb;
    
    double Cox = (epsox)/(xox*1.0E-8); //Oxide capacitance per unit area, [F/cm2]
    double A = 1.0/Cox;
    double G = ((Na*Ndpoly))/((ni*ni));
    double fgs = -((kTq)*log(G)); 
    double B = A*Qf;

    
    double T = Na/ni;
    double J = 2*kTq*log(T);
    
    
    double K = 2*q*epsSi*Na*J;
    double C = sqrt(K);
    
    
    double W = (q*DI)*(1.0/(Cox));
    double D = W;
    
    
    double U = 2*q*epsSi*Na;
    double F = sqrt(U);
    
    
    
    
    double ginomeno1 = J + Vsb;
    
    double tetragwniki_tou_ginomenou1 = sqrt(ginomeno1);
    double H = tetragwniki_tou_ginomenou1;
    
    double ginomeno2 = J;
    double tetragwniki_tou_ginomenou2 = sqrt(ginomeno2);
    double L = tetragwniki_tou_ginomenou2;
    
    
    
    double v1 = vFB(fgs, B);
    double v2 = vSP(J);
    double v3 = vT(A,C);
    double v4 = vA(W); 
    double v5 = gamwt(A,F);
    double v6 = roulis(H,L);
    double v7 = thres_volt(v1,v2,v3,v4);
    double v8 = zero_body_bias_threshold_voltage (v7,v5,v6);
     
    double FocmtofFoum = 1.0E11; //Conversion factor of F/cm to fF/um
    double Coxnew = Cox*FocmtofFoum;
    
    
    
    printf ("Cox = %e [F/cm2]\n",Cox);
    printf ("Coxnew = %f [fF/um]\n",Coxnew);
    printf ("VFB = %f [V]\n", v1);
    printf ("Vsp = %f [V]\n", v2);
    printf ("Vt =%f [V]\n", v3);
    printf ("Va = %f [V]\n", v4);
    printf ("gamma = %f [V ^1/2]\n", v5);
    printf ("Give me a number for Vsb..");
    scanf  ("%f", &Vsb);
    
    if (Vsb==0)
    
    ginomeno1 = J;
    
    printf ("V_body_bias = %f [V]\n", v8);
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}

double vFB (double fgs, double B) 
{
return (fgs-B);
}

double vT (double A, double C){ 
return (A*C);
}

double vA (double D){ 
return (+D);
}

double vSP (double J)  
{ 
return (+J);
}


double gamwt (double A, double F)
{
       return (A*F);
}

     
double roulis( double H, double L)
{
       return (H-L);
}


double thres_volt(double vFB, double vSP, double vT, double vA)
{
return (vFB+vSP+vT+vA);
}


double zero_body_bias_threshold_voltage(double thresh_volt, double gamwt, double roulis)
{
       return (thresh_volt + gamwt*roulis);
}
```

Comment: You are taking Vsb in input after you have used in `double ginomeno1 = J + Vsb;`, why?

Comment: @kiner_shah I don't understand your question.Ginomeno1 refers to the sum of the first square root in formula 1.26 inside the parenthesis.So Vsb must be implemented there

Comment: You can check where is `Vsb` defined and used in your code - you will understand my query.

Comment: I'm not very good at this, so if you could give me the answer that I need, you would help me a lot!

Comment: You are setting the value of `ginomeno1` way before `scanf` of `Vsb` i.e. `double ginomeno1 = J + Vsb;` is before `scanf  ("%f", &Vsb);`. Is that ok for you? I think `scanf` should come first.

Answer (score 1):

You might think that the statement `double ginomeno1 = J + Vsb;` defines a formula stored in `ginomeno1`. But this is not the case, it is an assignment.

Programs in C execute their statements **in sequence**. Your error is in the order of your statements, here in excerpts slightly formatted for better readability:

```c
/* ... */
int main() {
    /* ... */
    double Vsb;
    /* ... */
    double ginomeno1 = J + Vsb;
    /* ... */
    double v8 = zero_body_bias_threshold_voltage (v7,v5,v6);
    /* ... */
    printf ("Give me a number for Vsb..");
    scanf("%f", &Vsb);
    /* ... */
    if (Vsb == 0)
        ginomeno1 = J;
    /* ... */
    printf("V_body_bias = %f [V]\n", v8);
    /* ... */
```

The assignment to `ginomeno1` uses the value of `Vsb` at the time of its encounter, and this is undefined. The expression on the right hand side of `=` is calculated and stored in the variable `ginomeno1`, giving you *any* result.

The same holds true for the latter conditionally executed assignment. Changing `ginomeno1` will not automagically change the value of `v8`. BTW, dropping the addition in case of a zero value is not necessary, as the second operand is zero. ;-)

The solution is to reorder the statements, which is left as an enlightening exercise to you.